# Is $f(x)-\left\lfloor f(x)\right\rfloor$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function. Define $h:(0,1)\to[0,1]$ such that, $$h(x)=f(x)-\left\lfloor f(x)\right\rfloor$$Is $h$ continuous? Here $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CEQQFjAGahUKEwiHtt2er6HHAhVBBo4KHTHGAGU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FFloorFunction.html&ei=8RfKVcf5GMGMuASxjIOoBg&usg=AFQjCNHELl1VhlrQZPnRxx_Yduw2VQQfCA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E).

This problem arose due to solving another problem in Real Analysis. Intuitively, it seems that $h$ is continuous but I can neither prove or disprove it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm..... Consider $f(x) = x$. Easy to prove that in this case $h(x)$ is not continuous. To prove something false, you only need one exception, don't you?

Comment: Why do you think it will be continuous? It will be full of dicontinuities, eg the step function x-[x]

Comment: If $f(x)$ is not constant then in general wherever $f(x)=1$, the continuity could be compromised.

Comment: Note that the range of $h$ cannot be $[0,1]$, but $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $f(x)$ is known to be $[0,1]$, so that $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor=0$, except where $f(x)=1$, then $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor=1$. So $h(x)$ is $f(x)$, except when $f(x)=1$, then $h(x)=0$ and there is a discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
2x \, & \text{if} &  0 \leq x \leq 1/2\\
-2x+2 \,& \text{if} & 1/2 < x \leq 1\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $h(x)$ will be discontinuous at $x=1/2$ because $f$ takes the value $1$ at $x=1/2$.

In general, wherever $f$ takes the value $1$, the continuity will be compromised, unless $f$ is the constant function taking the value $1$.